# Is there any closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^{r}\binom{n}{k}$?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

Is there any elementary way to derive a closed form for the following sum:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^{r}\binom{n}{k}$$

Where $r$ is a fixed number.

I tried like that:

$$\left(1+x\right)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{k}$$
Taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$ yields:

$$n\left(1+x\right)^{\left(n-1\right)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}kx^{\left(k-1\right)}$$

Multiplying both sides by $x$:

$$xn\left(1+x\right)^{\left(n-1\right)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}kx^{k}$$

Again taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$:
$$n\left(1+x\right)^{\left(n-1\right)}+xn\left(n-1\right)\left(1+x\right)^{\left(n-2\right)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}k^{2}x^{\left(k-1\right)}$$

But I don't know if repeating this process will give us a good closed form (if I was sure then finally we just need to set $x=1$ to get what we want).

I know the answer when $r=0$ and that easily can be derived , but the exponential $r$ is something that prevents me of computing, any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use moments of binomial distribution

$$E_p(X^r)=\sum_{x=0}^{n} x^r \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x} $$

for $p=.5$

$$\sum_{x=0}^{n} x^r \binom{n}{x}=2^n E_{p=.5}(X^r).$$

For $E(X^r)$ see [Knoblauch (2008)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40233780).

Comment: then what would be the LHS?

Comment: Closed form of  the moments of the binomial distribution

Answer (score 1):

We can find a representation in terms of *[falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)* of $n$. Let $r$ be a positive integer. We can represent $k^r$ in terms of *[Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Definition)*:
\begin{align*}
k^r=\sum_{j=1}^r{r\brace j}k^{\underline{j}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
with falling factorials $k^{\underline{j}}=k(k-1)\cdots(k-j+1)$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}k^r}&=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\sum_{j=1}^r{r\brace j}k^{\underline{j}}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^r{r\brace j}\sum_{k=j}^n\binom{n}{k}k^{\underline{j}}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^r{r\brace j}n^{\underline{j}}\sum_{k=j}^n\binom{n-j}{k-j}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^r{r\brace j}n^{\underline{j}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\binom{n-j}{k}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=1}^r2^{n-j}{r\brace j}n^{\underline{j}}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we substitute $k^r$ according to (1).
- In (3) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.
- In (4) we shift the index to start with $j=0$.

> **Note:** With  regard to a comment we derive a representation from which we might conclude, that a closed form is not within reach.

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series. This way we can write for instance, recalling the Taylor series representation of $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{z^n}{n!}$:
\begin{align*}
r![z^r]e^{kz}=k^r\tag{5}
\end{align*}

We obtain using (5)
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}k^r&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}r![z^r]e^{kz}\\
&=r![z^r]\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(e^z\right)^k\\
&=r![z^r]\left(1+e^z\right)^n\\
&=r![z^r]\left(2+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{6}+\cdots+\frac{z^r}{r!}\right)^n
\end{align*}
The  last line  indicates  that  extraction of the coefficient  of $z^r$ in closed form is not feasible.

Comment: Cannot it be done using Egorychev method?

Comment: @user715522: No, Egorychevs method does not provide a closed form. In fact it boils down to $r![z^r](1+e^z)^n$ with $[z^r]$ the coefficient of $z^r$ which does not have a closed form solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but finally cannot we find any closed form for this expression? (I searched for that and the available articles on the internet are not free unfortunately,so I still don't know either there exist a closed form or not.)

Comment: @user715522:  You're  welcome.  I've  added a note which indicates that a closed form is not within reach.

Comment: What is your opinion about the other post? I mean using  moments of binomial distribution.

Comment: @user715522: The connection of the moments with your sum is not clear to me.